# Does melatonin change the appearance of humans?

Tags: melatonin

Melatonin (not to be confused with melanin) was sold as a wonder drug during the 90s. I remember images of mice, which supposedly got a more beautiful fur. I would like to know whether the effect is true and whether it also has an effect on humans skin (or appearance in general).

Obviously, googling about melatonin generates a lot of suspicious results.

Answer (score 4):

Melatonin is a hormone produced by the pineal gland located in the brain, and its production is inhibited by light to the retina and permitted by darkness ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melatonin#Humans)). It has a lot of effects on the body ([reference](http://www.lef.org/magazine/mag2012/sep2012_7-Ways-Melatonin-Attacks-Aging-Factors_01.htm)) but I will stick to just discussing its apparent effects on aging and skin.

Melatonin works as an antioxidant and helps in removing free radicals from the body ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14740000)). Research has shown that free radicals could damage the skin ([reference](http://www.healthy-info.co.uk/skin/How_Free_Radicals_Damage_Skin_Cells.html)), so I would have to conclude that melatonin could have a part to play in maintaining the beauty of your skin.

It is a known fact that melatonin levels in the body decrease from age, and its decrease has been correlated with some of the effects of aging ([reference](http://press.endocrine.org/doi/full/10.1210/jcem.85.6.6660)). As you have mentioned in your question, there is research proving that melatonin could decrease the effect of aging in rats ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10650927)). Also melatonin was found to increase the youthful rhythmic activity in a shrew ([reference](http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0005904)). In the paper titled [melatonin and skin aging](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23467217) it has been stated that

> In UV-induced solar damage, melatonin distinctly counteracts massive
> generation of reactive oxygen species, mitochondrial and DNA damage.
> Thus, there is considerable evidence for melatonin to be an effective
> anti-skin aging compound.

Moreover in the paper titled "[On the Role of Melatonin in Skin Physiology and Pathology](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1317110/)", it has been proposed that

> Melatonin (synthesized locally or delivered topically) could
> counteract or buffer external (environmental) or internal stresses to
> preserve the biological integrity of the skin and to maintain its
> homeostasis.

So in conclusion, I would have to say that melatonin does have a lot of positive effects on the skin but, given that it is a hormone and there are side effects ([reference](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-940-MELATONIN.aspx?activeIngredientId=940&activeIngredientName=MELATONIN)), it should be used in moderation.